# Using Java 8, how do I parallelize matrix-vector multiplication efficiently?

Tags: java, vector, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Given some fixed implementation of sparse vectors `SparseVectorDouble` (basically an index and a value array) and vector multiplication, I want to implement parallelized matrix-vector multiplication. I tried the following approach based on the all-new stream framework.

```
ArrayList<SparseVectorDouble> rows;

//...

public double[] multiply(final double[] vector, final double[] result)
{
    final IntToDoubleFunction multiply = (index) -> rows.get(index).multiply(vector);
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(result, multiply);
    return result;
}
```

However, the speedup using a dual-core CPU with Hyperthreading is only about 20% for huge matrices (16M x 16M matrix; approx. 10 entries each row).

1. Is the above code a suitable parallelization or does suffer from some assumptions in the parallel stream processing framework?
2. How do I effectively benchmark the CPU-usage of such a task?

Edit #1:
The vector multiplication in class SparseVectorDouble is basically implemented as follows:

```
protected double multiplyThisDefaultZero(final double[] other) {
    assert defaultValue == 0.0;

    if (!(size() <= other.length)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("vector of matching size expected");
    }

    double sumXY = 0;

    for (int internalIndex = 0; internalIndex < internalSize; internalIndex ++) {
        final int index = indices[internalIndex];
        sumXY += values[internalIndex] * other[index];
    }

    return sumXY;
}
```

Comment: To get a significant speedup you'd probably need to do something more customized.

Comment: Are you using `jnt.linear_algebra.SparseVectorDouble`? Or your own sparse vector implementation? If so, please provide `SparseVectorDouble.multiply` method.

Comment: Since I have to stick to some other implementation, I added the relevant code to the question.